# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Titolo' cannot be null

Tags: php

This error continue to pop up and i can't find any solution this is the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
if ($_POST['function']=='insert'){  
if ($_POST['Titolo'] == '' || $_POST['Eta'] == ''|| $_POST['Piattaforma'] == ''|| $_POST['NGioc'] == ''){

        echo'<p>Attenzione riempire i campi obbligatori';
    }
}
    else{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=videogamelist', 'root', 'root',array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    $sql = "insert into games (Copertina,Titolo,Descrizione,Eta,Piattaforma,NGioc,Genere,DUscita,Sviluppatore) 
    values (:Copertina,:Titolo,:Descrizione,:Eta,:Piattaforma,:NGioc,:Genere,:DUscita,:Sviluppatore)";
    $res_prepare = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $res_prepare->bindParam(':Copertina',$_POST['Copertina']);
    $res_prepare->bindParam(':Titolo',$_POST['Titolo']);
    $res_prepare->bindParam(':Descrizione',$_POST['Descrizione']);
    $res_prepare->bindParam(':Eta',$_POST['Eta']);
    $res_prepare->bindParam(':Piattaforma',$_POST['Piattaforma']);
    $res_prepare->bindParam(':NGioc',$_POST['NGioc']);
    $res_prepare->bindParam(':Genere',$_POST['Genere']);
    $res_prepare->bindParam(':DUscita',$_POST['DUscita']);
    $res_prepare->bindParam(':Sviluppatore',$_POST['Sviluppatore']);
    $res_prepare->execute();
    echo'Gioco inserito';
    }
?>
```

Almost all the record give this error and if i allow null value it will input only null value

Comment: I think your else is attached to the wrong if. It should be the else for the inner if, not the outer one. As far as why `$_POST['Titolo']` is empty when you're expecting it not to be, my first guess would be that the form input is misnamed.

Comment: thanks the problem was the if